# How can I export data to a CSV using Symfony without running out of memory?

Tags: php, csv, symfony1, symfony-1.4, export-to-csv

I've run into this issue a few times.

I have a piece of code that exports data to a CSV.  The method I'm using passes the result set to the template, the template cycles through the results, echoing the fields.

In the action:

```
$this->result = ObjectPeer::doSelect($criteria);
```

In the template:

```
foreach ($result as $row)
{
  echo $row->getValue1().','.$row->getValue2().','.$row->getValue3()...
}
```

However, if the result set is large, I'll run out of memory:

```
 [error] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1556481 bytes) in exportSuccess.php on line 13, referer: https://mysite.com/module
```

The process is using over 250 mb, but the file it creates is only ~2 mb.
I can up the amount of memory that php.ini gives the process, but I'd rather not.  If the export is large enough, I kind of doubt i'll be able to give it enough memory.

I've read a few other cases similar to this, which suggested unsetting $row after each echo.  That didn't work in my case.

I assume there is a way to chunk this query and still build the whole file - can anyone recommend or point me to a clear tutorial?

Comment: Are you using propel or doctrine? Which hydration method do you use?

Comment: Propel.  I'm just calling doSelect on the peer class with some criteria where relevant.

Comment: Propel 1.6 I guess, could you paste the query you made? How many items do you have in your table?

Comment: I think it's propel 1.4?  I don't have the newer propel plugin installed here (and for purposes of this question, i can't install it).   In this instance, about 10k rows.  Although it could be way more than that in the future.

Comment: Ok for the propel version. Could you add the detail of the `$criteria`?

Comment: RE: $criteria - It varies.  When it's failing, there is generally no criteria, thus returning the maximum number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on number of elements you want to retrieve (ie: `getValue1`, `getValue2`, etc ..), you can hydrate the result [in a different way](http://trac.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.4/Criteria#CustomizingSelectColumns):

```
$stmt = ObjectPeer::doSelectStmt($m_criteria);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
{
  echo $row[0];
}
```

Also, you can check another solution using `doSelectRS`:

```
$rs = ObjectPeer::doSelectRS($criteria);
$rs->setFetchMode(ResultSet::FETCHMODE_ASSOC);

while($rs->next())
{
  $records = $rs->getRow();
  // then use $records['key'] to retrieve information
}
```

Few others things that you can check. This french aticle about [memory leak form Propel](http://team-fusion.pmsipilot.com/891/eviter-les-fuites-memoire-avec-propel/).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a basic idea to write to a csv file. this doesn't show the connection to the database but it is everything afterwards and make sure to close the connection at the end.

```
$filename = 'c:\whatever.csv';

$fp = fopen($filename, "w")  or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to ".$filename." <br>";


$res = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM $table1 

WHERE Something
");

// fetch a row and write the column names out to the file
echo mysql_error();
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach($row as $name => $value) {
$line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
$comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);

// remove the result pointer back to the start
mysql_data_seek($res, 0);

// and loop through the actual data
echo mysql_error();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach($row as $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
    $comma = ",";

}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);
}
```